# Detail and total all transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, rollup

I need to detail & total all transactions for the month to date (Group by with Roll Up)

My sales table contains:

```
SALES_ID, 
EMPLOYEE_ID, 
PRODUCT_ID, 
CUSTOMER_ID, 
SALES_AMOUNT, 
QUANTITY, 
TRANSACTION_DATE, 
SUPPLIER
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I'm not sure what "group by with roll up" has to do with your question.

Comment: We have lots of ideas. But you leave a lot out of your question, making it difficult to choose one. What have you tried? Remember that SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).